# This code is undefined, why is it running? How do i crash it?

Tags: c++

I ran the code below in visual studios and expected to get a runtime or some kind of error. I got nothing, absolutely nothing. I got the output code 9, comment that line out and got 3. I ran it on codepad and it gave me no errors as well.

Is there a compiler that will tell me this code is incorrect? If it is correct why is it? I know const A& [is legal](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) but AFAIK the below isnt.

```
class A
{
public:
    int v;
    A& get()
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

A& func()
{
    A a;
    a.v=3;
    return a.get();
}

int main()
{
    A& v = func();
    v.v=9;
    return v.v;
}
```

Comment: Some tools, such as PC-lint by Gimpel Software, can detect bugs like this.

Comment: "full power" pointer analysis is a cutting edge research area of static analysis, as I understand it.  You might have heard about seL4 that NICTA released last year or so - it had to restrict pointers and references to prove aspects of the code. Part of the seminal work (PhD dissertations) in the seL4 project was C reference static analysis. Or, to put it another way, "automated pointer analysis at compile time is absurdly hard today"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.  You can't expect it to do anything in particular, including crash.

There is no compiler I know of that will catch all types of UB and I don't think it's possible.  You could crank up the warning level of your compiler but I don't think it would even warn you then.  Your use of get() as the way of capturing a reference to a local variable will, I believe, effectively hide the fact that this is what you're doing from most, if not all compilers.  The amount of effort that would be required to catch such instances of suicide don't seem to me to be worth it.

That's just part of the life of a C++ developer.

Comment: I might accept this. I tried returning a instead of a.get() and it does in fact warn me. Good! So +1

Comment: I had a similar problem recently, except with the return of std::string, which was not stored just a temp variable (therefore not copied). It never warned me, and even worked correctly... 50% of the time. The rest of the time only half the string would actually still exist when it was used; it was a pain to find that.
So given the right opportunity, this example would bite you in the butt, just have to give it time.

Comment: The compiler's job is to crank out machine code nothing else. It may but does not HAVE to warn you if you do something stupid.

Comment: @doron - that's only sort of true.  There are several things that an implementation is explicitly supposed to give warnings about.  This isn't one of them but it's an easy enough one to implement.

Comment: @Daniel - crank up your warning level to max.  I don't know any compiler that doesn't warn when you directly return a ref to local.

Comment: I'm using GCC, and have -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors, if theres something more to add for warnings, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

It's working because the memory the instance was being stored in hadn't been overwritten yet. This obviously wouldn't fly in a real project.

Comment: Obviously it shouldnt. I tried writing A& b = func(); b.v=5; after func() but before v.v=9 and i got nothing mentioning i corrupted memory. Which sucks. I said references are always safe but i decided to test compilers and returning references. Looks like it isnt safe as a return value

Comment: @acidzombie24: It is valid as a return value, as long as the referred to object is valid. What you are doing is the reference equivalent of using a pointer after delete.

Comment: It may or may not "fly" in a real project.  It could continue to work for years until one day it just doesn't.

Comment: The only reason it works is that the local variables used in the function have been popped off the stack but nothing has pushed back onto the stack. Were you to call new functions with new local variables, you will start seeing weird behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Using a reference to a local object after it has gone out of scope is undefined behavior, and as such it does not require any diagnostic from the compiler.

> **1.3.12 undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, such as might arise upon use of an erroneous program construct or erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements. Undefined behavior may also be expected when this International Standard omits the description of any explicit definition of behavior. [Note: ***permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results***, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
> diagnostic message).

---

You ask why can't it be detected at runtime; how can that be? The only way would be to check, at every memory access done via a pointer/reference whose value is in the range currently used for the stack, that such address is below the current stack pointer.

This would be a hugely costly operation (in terms both of time spent and executable size increase) since it would have to be done for *every* memory access, so it's not done.

On the other hand, the checks for the arrays you described work (AFAIK) by checking if a flag value put between stack frames has been overwritten, and such check is performed only when the function returns (by the way, such checks in VC++ can be enabled only in unoptimized builds).

Another kind of check that the compiler can do is by static analysis of the code; this is not perfect, but often works fine, and warns you if you do something nonsensical as directly returning a reference/pointer to a local variable; in this case it didn't warn you because your example is quite convoluted, and the static analysis didn't manage to catch it.

Comment: Same thing i said to the other guy who deleted his answer. I am not asking why it is undefined. I am asking why no compiler is reporting this during runtime debug. I know MSVC reports accessing arrays outside of range, but there doesnt seem anything for this

Comment: I'm not saying why it's undefined, I'm saying that, being that UB, doing nothing at all is a perfectly valid behavior. Still, I'll expand my answer.

Comment: It IS undefined behavior exactly because it is hard do detect the error in all cases. Therefore the standard says that compilers don't have to. Most of them reports the obvious cases anyway, and passes on the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making a big logical mistake. Undefined Behavior doesn't mean that a program will crash... it means that anything could happen.

If you're lucky (very very lucky) then you get a crash. What normally happens instead is that if you do anything that implies undefined behavior simply the program keeps running as if nothing happened, until one million executed instructions later where a perfectly legal piece of code does something very crazy. Normal reactions from programmers is then to blame the compiler, the OS version, the defective RAM and voodoo dolls hidden by hostile colleagues in the drawer.

If you are just a little unlucky instead the program will just behave exactly as you would expect, including providing the result you expect from it and closing fine without any problems at all. All this until you get to the big demo day, when instead it will crash badly in front of the audience just after you say "And now let's save our work...".

But why isn't undefined behavior checked in C++?

One of the main philosophical foundation of C++ is simply that programmers make no error. This means that when a programmer does indeed make an error there is no "runtime error angel" that will come to help, just "undefined behavior daemons" that instead will try to bite.

This has been done to avoid leaving enough space for another language between C++ and assembler, so it must be possible to write efficient code, and runtime error angels are too heavy to carry around. While for sure it's easy to write bloated and slow code in C++ it's also possible to write efficient code if you have a good grasp of how the language works and by keeping a constant focus to performance in mind.

When you see "this is undefined behavior" simply the meaning is that the compiler writers are free to ignore whatever is going to happen. Checking that those rules are not violated is a burden on the programmers that are using C++, not on the C++ compiler.

In my opinion the very fact that "undefined behavior" means that's unpredictable what happens and the fact that's very very easy to get undefined behavior by mistake means that C++ is a terrible language to learn by experimentation, because when you make a mistake the system won't tell you clearly so. It's also in my opinion a terrible language for a beginner (because it's natural for beginners to do more mistakes).

The only reasonable path to C++ is:

1. Learning it by studying and not by experimenting

   C++ is a complex language with a long evolution history. In some parts it's illogical because of historical accidents. Even if you're smart you will never be able to guess the historical reasons for an apparently illogical choice. History must be studied.
2. You must think very carefully at every single statement you write

   Like I said before you can't expect C++ to detect all your mistakes. Anything can happen when you make a mistake (including nothing!) and this means that debugging can be very very hard. The only viable option is to try to not introduce bugs. Writing code without serious thinking and hoping that tests and debug will find them is IMO bad for any language, but a true suicidal approach to C++.

Comment: +1 only because your username is 6502. Yes that would be unlucky, but i was hoping something will hint that the code is no longer valid. I mean, it checks if arrays are out of range but theres nothing for references with simple piece of code. But, i was kind of expecting that. But i hope A compiler checks it

Comment: @acidzombie24: I extended the explanation adding a description of why C++ doesn't detect UB (basically because it would cost too much and it's against the language philosophy to punish good programmers with inefficient code just to help sloppy programmers or beginners - C++ is just not the language for them).

Answer (score 1):

To give an example why this is definetly undefined behaviour; change the following in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
// ...
int main() {
    A& v = func();
    v.v=9;

    int over[9000] = {1};
    std::cout << v.v;

    return 0;
}
```

At least for me (and consistently), that overwrote the memory stored in v.v. But it may not be consistent for others, because how memory is handled is probably implementation Dependant. It should give you an idea however.

Comment: Wow, why does that overwrite memory? on codepad it didnt http://codepad.org/GS0ygxCy, in msvc it did. I used this `std::cout << std::hex << v.v; std::cout << std::hex << v.v; std::cout << std::hex << v.v;` and got random number, -1, -1 (but in hex);. Also i edit your answer for humor purposes.

Comment: @acidzombie24: It's possible that because over[9000] is not used that codepad optimized it away. Or it may also be possible that the compilers are allowed to reorder the stack of primitive types (ie: put int over[9000] at the top of the function). Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't tell that it's invalid code. Returning `*this` as a reference would be OK if the reference lifetime was shorter than the lifetime of the object being returned. Determining which has the longer lifetime at runtime is beyond the capabilities of the compiler at compile-time, since the lifetime can in general depend on what happens at run-time.

I suppose a sufficiently clever compiler (or more likely, lint tool) could put in checks for certain special cases, possibly including the case you give here. The question is whether it's worth implementing such a check when it will only catch obvious cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone said, the typical stack implementation on a modern OS allocates stack in 4-8KB increments (pages). Stack usage at program startup is typically small, the object data exists several bytes past the top of stack. Even if only one stack page is allocated, there's a decent chunk of prefectly read-writeable space past the stack top. So reading from that memory does not cause a runtime error.

But yes, it's an undefined behavior.